# How can I calculate with optional parameter in \newcommand block?

Tags: latex

I want to have a grid-command which is adjustable to the wanted height. Here is what I did:

```
\newcommand{\vhlines}[1]{
    \hspace{1em}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.75cm}
    \begin{picture}(22,#1)
        \color{lightgray}
        \linethickness{0.075mm}
        \multiput(0,0)(1,0){21}
        {\line(0,1){#1}} % need to subtract 1 from #1
        \multiput(0,0)(0,1){#1}
        {\line(1,0){20}}
    \end{picture}
 }
```

If I call, e.g., `\vhlines{16}` I find the vertical lines to be too long on the upper end. They are correct if I write a `15` instead of the `#1` in the line with the comment.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform elementary numeric (integer) expressions using `\numexpr`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\vhlines}[1]{%
  \hspace{1em}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{0.75cm}%
  \begin{picture}(22,#1)
    \color{lightgray}
    \linethickness{0.075mm}
    \multiput(0,0)(1,0){21}
      {\line(0,1){\numexpr#1-1}}
    \multiput(0,0)(0,1){#1}
      {\line(1,0){20}}
  \end{picture}
 }
\begin{document}

\noindent
\vhlines{4}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, for more complex expressions, add to your preamble

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

which would allow you to use `\calc{<your numerical expression>}`.